# Problema Maven eclipse: No version available for xxx within specifie

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Accidentalmente le di stop a una descarga de Maven en eclipse y mi proyecto quedo corrupto, ¿alguien sabe como arreglarlo? Me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer no descargo bien algunas dependencias, pero necesito una solución que funcione para todos las dependencias, ya que dice que son 78. Cabe mencionar que en la pestaña pom.xml no me marca errores y en java build path también están todos los jar de forma correcta sin errores. El error solo me aparece en lo que muestro en la imagen y mi proyecto no funciona.

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer Project -> Clean (y seleccionas sólo el que te marca como error) y después, clickando con el botón derecho sobre el proyecto, Maven -> Update project?

Comment: Si y no funciona

Comment: Normalmente debería bastar para que se descargue las dependencias que te puedan faltar, lo único que se me ocurre es que compruebas el compilador de java que tengas seleccionado en el proyecto, que compruebes que es el mismo que para el IDE y que después ejecutes las fase de Maven: clean e install.